# cannot calculate data correctly according to input based on the same category

Tags: php, sum, laravel-query-builder, calculated-field, laravel-5.7

### Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subDay()->startOfWeek()->toDateString();
    $nowDate = Carbon::now()->today()->toDateString();

    $spent_time = SpentTime::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();
    $task_category = $spent_time->task_category;

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{

        $spent_time->spent_time   = SpentTime::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_spent_time', $spent_time->daily_spent_time , $fromDate);
        $spent_time['spent_time'] = $spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;

        $spent_time->percentage   = SpentTime::where('task_category',$task_category)
                                    ->sum('daily_percentage', $spent_time->daily_percentage, $fromDate);
        $spent_time['percentage'] = $spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;
        return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

> when creating new data with the same category, and inputting the data value, it should be able to calculate the data correctly, but this cannot

[image]

> calculation does not match the input value

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Model

```
public static function findOrCreate($plan_id, $data)
{
    $spent_time = static::where('plan_id', $plan_id)->first();
    $task_category = $spent_time->task_category;

    if (is_null($spent_time)) {
        return static::create($data);
    }else{
        $spent_time['spent_time'] = $spent_time->spent_time + $spent_time->daily_spent_time;
        $spent_time['percentage'] = $spent_time->percentage  + $spent_time->daily_percentage;

    return $spent_time->update($data);
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{      
    $spent_time = SpentTime::findOrCreate($request->get('plan_id'), [
        'plan_id' => $request->get ('plan_id'),
        'daily_spent_time' => $request->get ('daily_spent_time'),
        'daily_percentage' => $request->get ('daily_percentage'),
        'reason' => $request->get ('reason'),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('real.index', compact( 'spent_time'));
}
```